# PHP CSV max number

Tags: php, csv

So I open a CSV file with my code and I get this output:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Possibilities
            [1] =>  First
            [2] =>  Second
            [3] =>  Third
            [4] =>  Forth
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lower chance
            [1] =>  28
            [2] =>  24
            [3] =>  16
            [4] =>  30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Higher chance
            [1] =>  30
            [2] =>  42
            [3] =>  44
            [4] =>  34
        )

)
```

Now I have a problem because I can't figure it out how to get a MAX number from [1]=>Array and [2]=>Array. And how to calculate average number between two arrays like [1][1] and [2][1] (avg from 28+30) ??

Comment: How much have you tried? Really...? You want the max number, any chance you tried to Google it?

Comment: Use this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php, to get the highest number, or you can make some if statements to do what you want.

Comment: I very new to PHP and I don't know how to do this sorry. @Andreas

Comment: @user6082465 did there is just [1] and [2] arrays you want to get the average from it? or there is more?

Comment: First I need max numbers in all arrays so first 30 and than 44. Next I need to calculate an average number between 28+30 and 24+42 and so on for all 4 number. Problem is that i dont even know how to just write 28 on screen with no calculations. @MohammedAlhanafi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr1 = $array[1];//get second array from the variable contain the arrays.
$arr2 = $array[2];//get third one from the variable contain the arrays.

echo max($arr1) . ' : ' . max($arr2) . '<br>';//Max 2 numbers in the both arrays.
echo $arr1[1], '+', $arr2[1], ' = ', $arr1[1]+$arr2[1], '<br>';//count first 2 elements from the first array.
echo $arr1[2], '+', $arr2[2], ' = ', $arr1[2]+$arr2[2], '<br>';//count first 2 elements from the second array.
echo $arr1[1], '+', $arr2[1], ' + ', $arr1[2], '+', $arr2[2], ' = ', $arr1[1]+$arr2[1]+$arr1[2]+$arr2[2];//count first 2 elements from both arrays.
```

Try this one.

**EDITED**

Code work fine for me, but if there is any problems with getting the integer elements, 
Just use the [`filter_var_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php)

```
$arr1 = filter_var_array($array[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$arr2 = filter_var_array($array[2], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Comment: Calculation work good thank you. The problem is that it shows like max number from 1st array and 2nd array are words written in them. For example MAX in 1st array should be 30 but it's "zmanjsanje prodaje"

Comment: @user6082465 Edited the answer,

Comment: @user6082465 Its a pleasure to help you :), Please click on `Click to accept this answer` on the left, to make your question as solved :), And welcome to the community.

Comment: Thank you. I still have one more question if im not bothering you :)

Comment: No no no, Just ask :).

Comment: So how can i make this: so if the max number in first array is 30 and it has index 4 it goes together with index 4 in [0] array? and the same goes with last array, max number is 44 which is index 3 and it goes together with "gradnja" from [0] array. So I would like to output "gradnja(44)" and "povezovanje(30)" for example.

Comment: I dont understand you, see if you can use `foreach()` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php and you can use `count()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php to get how many element in array, and sorry i want to leave, but please make sure to make more googling. Its really a pleasure to help you :).